# Movie/show with alien hand covered in mouths on man’s chest?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, robots

This is so far out there it might just be a fever dream. I have a strange memory of a sci fi show/movie with a man and a robot. The man gets captured by some sort of aliens who attempt to use mouths on their hands to eat some guys heart out of his chest?? I’m really not sure. I know this sounds wild lol but if I’m not making it up it’s something I’ve been trying to figure out for 20 years!

Comment: Can you at least say if this is live-action or animated?  What colour are the aliens?  How many are there?

Comment: Edgar Rice Burroughs'  *Barsoom* series has "Plant men" that suck blood through mouths on their hands. I don't know if this made it into either of the movies based off the books though.

Comment: Apart from the robot it sounds like the wraith from SG Atlantis (which premiered in 2004, so the timeframe fits, which makes me feel very old); no mouths, but "special organs" in the palm of their hands, and they feed at the approximate location of the heart on humans.

Comment: [Moontrap](https://youtu.be/270j3YK2YMU?t=110) has alien/robot trying to cut man's chest.